# How do I do a SWITCH or SELECT CASE in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

NetLogo does not have a native SWITCH, SWITCH-CASE, or SELECT-CASE type of multiple condition, how do I do the same thing without having a giant mess of nested `IF-ELSE` statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since NetLogo 6.1, NetLogo has supported multi-case `ifelse`, which can be used similarly to other languages' `switch` statements.  Here is [an example from the docs](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/6.2.1/docs/dictionary.html#ifelse):

```
ask patches [
  let choice random 4
  (ifelse
    choice = 0 [
      set pcolor red
      set plabel "r"
    ]
    choice = 1 [
      set pcolor blue
      set plabel "b"
    ]
    choice = 2 [
      set pcolor green
      set plabel "g"
    ]
    ; elsecommands
    [
      set pcolor yellow
      set plabel "y"
  ])
]
```

And here is the example from the other answer rewritten to use it:

```
;; example of SWITCH style conditional block 
(ifelse 
  (criteria-1) [ action-1 ]
  (criteria-2) [ action-2 ]
  (criteria-3) [ action-3 ]
               [ default-action ]
)
```

This does not need to have the "multi-close" of the `]` on the last line, so it overall seems cleaner to me.

Comment: Oh wow. That’s quite cool and the enclosing parentheses make it fit quite nicely with other NetLogo primitive variant symtax.  I’ve got some catching up to do! 
I think it would be good to combine the two answers, in that it’s still good practice to keep those kinds of code structures concise.

Answer (score 0):

We can simulate a SWITCH statement with a chain of nested IF-ELSE statements, formatted so it's not a big mess, and actually easy to read and edit.

We will format the chain of IF-ELSE statement with the following goals:

- avoid excessive indenting,
- avoid overly long code lines
- make it look more like switch in other languages
- rearranging the cases does not break the syntax
- there is a default case

#### A SWITCH Statement

Here's how it looks:

```
;; example of SWITCH style conditional block 
if-else [ criteria 1 ] [ action-1 ][
if-else [ criteria 2 ] [ action-2 ][
if-else [ criteria 3 ] [ action-3 ][
if-else [ true ]       [ default-action ][
]]]]
```

#### Other considerations

Some programmers may find it offensive to have a default action that tests for `true`, and leaves the "else block" if the final "IF" empty. You can do what you like. I find making the default case explicit, makes all the actions formatted exactly the same, and avoids an awkward cluster of punctuation at the end.

- Avoid overly long lines--it makes it harder to read
- Keep conditions short--wrap them in reporter if needed.
- Keep actions short--wrap them in procedures if needed.
- This helps the code read more like a story and less like code.